# Linux messed up GUID Partition Table for APFS container on external drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition, apfs

I partitioned my 1TB external drive as follows for use with both macOS & Windows:

1. 949GB ***APFS***
2. 51GB ***Windows NTFS***

As I no longer needed the Windows partition I tried to delete it through Disk Utility. The various changes that came along with the APFS complicated the process for me and I only managed to somehow turn the NTFS partition into free space but could not merge it into APFS due to '*Container*' system I was unfamiliar with.

On the other hand, I had a PopOS! live USB at hand, so I tried to convert the free space to a FAT32 partition so that I could at least see that as such in Disk Utility. But had no further success in converting it into APFS & merge with the main partition.

So at some point, out of frustration, I decided that I might as well install PopOS! on this 51GB partition so I could try it out for a few days as Linux is generally fast on my 2015 Macbook Pro 13″.

Some error crept up and it said it was unable to complete the installation. So I dropped the idea & plugged my HDD back into macOS but to my dismay the main APFS container was unmountable. So after some quick Google-fu, I found that my GPT which should be `7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` was `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF`

`diskutil list`, disk in question

[image: Screenshot of the Terminal output for 'diskutil list']

`sudo gpt -r show disk2` output

[image: Screenshot of the Terminal output for 'sudo gpt -r show disk2']

Any way to access the APFS container without losing data (no backups sadly)?

Comment: Your two partitions total to 1.5G in the first place - I am surprised that anything worked.

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=FFFFFFFF

Comment: Thanks for responding @Tetsujin. Although I know the nature of problem, I still am confused about the sector size stuff. Just correcting the GPT partition type will be enough or I do have to do some additional work too?

Answer (score 2):

So I was able to access the drive as before just by changing its GUID back, by running

```
sudo sgdisk -g -t 2:7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/sdb
```

in Linux terminal.

[image]

I was then able to add the free disk space back to main APFS partition through Disk Utility by deleting it ('-' button in tool bar), which also dealt with the *'Suspicious MBR at Sector 0'*.

[image]

Comment: I've rolled back your question edit, please post the answer as an edit to the answer. Also, we usually prefer if people copy/paste Terminal output as text because this is easier to read for a lot of people.