# Need help with a corrupt macOS partition

Tags: disk-utility, partition, error

To cut a long story short, I decided to dual boot macOS Monterey with Ubuntu 22.04 as I needed it for some tasks that were easier on Linux. I found Bluetooth support to be janky and had to use a wired USB keyboard and mouse to get my tasks done. So I decided I did not want to keep Ubuntu on my system long-term. The simplest solution I read online was to delete the Ubuntu partition from within macOS and remerge the volumes to recover the space. While this worked for swap, this did not work for the Ubuntu partition and I ended up with a FFFFFF on my macOS volume. Attaching the `diskutil` info below:

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF ⁨⁩              459.9 GB   disk0s2
                    (free space)                         8.1 GB     -
   3:                  Apple_HFS ⁨UNTITLED⁩                31.6 GB    disk0s4
                    (free space)                         268.4 MB   -

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +459.9 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     205.8 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 231.3 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.4 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.4 GB    disk1s5s1
```

I have read some articles here about recovering the volume but am a touch unclear on the steps to take. The only thing I have done so far is make a bootable Monterey USB stick. I would appreciate it if someone would help me by creating a step-by-step guide that I can follow blindly to ensure that macOS boots normally when I restart the system. Kindly let me know if any more information is needed from my end.

PS: My data is backed up to iCloud so if needed I can reinstall macOS from scratch. However, I would prefer to use `diskutil` commands in recovery to solve the problem if possible.

Comment: Please search before posting - https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=FFFFFFFF

Comment: Yup I did search but the most relevant answer is from 5 years back. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff

Should I follow those instructions exactly or are there any changes in the intervening years that make them out of date?

Comment: Actually, the [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451126/linux-messed-up-guid-partition-table-for-apfs-container-on-external-drive) asked 2 days ago and answered yesterday should work. You may have to make adjustments to the  parameters of the `sgdisk` command to get the correct disk.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I tried that command but the terminal gave me an error saying sudo: no such command found.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Edit: Tried the sgdisk command without sudo and terminal said sgdisk command not found. I am using the terminal from macOS recovery.

Comment: The first sentence of [the posted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451126/linux-messed-up-guid-partition-table-for-apfs-container-on-external-drive/451148#451148) clearly states *"in Linux terminal"*.

Comment: Ah, my bad. assumed Mac Recovery terminal would work fine.

Have now booted from a Ubuntu live USB and tried the command. Volumes are currently unmounted. Getting the following error.

*Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format in memory*

Warning! Main partition table overlaps the first partition by 32 blocks! You will need to delete this partition or resize in another utility.

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by 33 blocks! You will need to delete this partition or resize in another utility.

<continued in next comment>

Comment: <continued>

Could not change partition 2’s type code to 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC!
Error encounter, not saving changes.

Can you kindly guide me on what to do next?

Comment: Good to hear that you have been able to solve the problem. Can you please add the solution as an answer below so future visitors can find it more easily (I rolled back your question edit)?